# How to automatically randomize and count the saturation of data points?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

This might be a silly question, but here goes.

I have this data frame:

```
str(THAT_EXT_NODE)
'data.frame':   907 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ NODE: Factor w/ 103 levels "absurd","alarming",..: 15 66 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 53 ...
head(THAT_EXT_NODE)
NODE
1 clear
2 plain
3 clear
4 clear
5 clear
6 clear
```

I want to randomly sample the data, and then see how many many of the 907 data points I have to 'inspect' in order to cover all 103 words included. In other words, I want to find the cut-off point for the inclusion of new words, i.e. at 300, 500 or 700 of the data points.

The only solution I have come up with myself is to slice the data in sections and to compare the addition of each section to the previous ones. This is not ideal, and I don't really get it to work. I have thus worked along the following lines:

```
s <- sample(907)
df1 <- THAT_EXT_NODE[s[1:91],]
df2 <- THAT_EXT_NODE[s[92:182],] 

matches <- df1[df1%in%df2]
length(matches)

df.comp<-factor(c(as.character(df1),as.character(df2)))
unique(df.comp)
```

...and then created a 'df3' and compared it to df.comp and so on.

Any ideas how I can do this and get the answer to how many of the 907 data points and I have to go through to cover the 103 words included?

A small reproducible example:

```
dput(head(THAT_EXT_NODE, 20))
structure(list(NODE = structure(c(15L, 66L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 53L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 41L, 43L, 77L, 
15L), .Label = c("absurd", "alarming", "amazing", "anomalous", 
"appalling", "apparent", "appropriate", "arguable", "awful", 
"axiomatic", "believable", "breathtaking", "certain", "characteristic", 
"clear", "conceivable", "convenient", "crucial", "cruel", "desirable", 
"disappointing", "distressing", "doubtful", "emphatic", "essential", 
"evident", "explicit", "extraordinary", "fair", "false", "foolish", 
"fortunate", "funny", "good", "great", "heartening", "humiliating", 
"hypocritical", "imperative", "implicit", "important", "impossible", 
"improbable", "inconceivable", "incredible", "inescapable", "inevitable", 
"interesting", "intriguing", "ironic", "irrelevant", "irritating", 
"likely", "lucky", "ludicrous", "natural", "necessary", "needful", 
"normal", "notable", "noteworthy", "noticeable", "obvious", "odd", 
"paradoxical", "plain", "plausible", "poor", "positive", "possible", 
"probable", "proper", "regrettable", "relevant", "remarkable", 
"revealing", "right", "sad", "sensible", "shameful", "significant", 
"strange", "striking", "sufficient", "surprising", "symptomatic", 
"terrible", "true", "typical", "unavoidable", "understandable", 
"unexpected", "unfortunate", "unjust", "unlikely", "unnatural", 
"unreasonable", "unthinkable", "untrue", "well-established", 
"vital", "worrying", "wrong"), class = "factor")), .Names = "NODE", row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: with `sample(df[,1], 907, replace=T)` ?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I fairly new to R, but I don't understand how that tells me how many data points I have to go through until all 103 words are accounted for.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. You want to be sure to get all the 103 words or you want to have a reasonable probability? If the former, you may need to inspect all the dataset if for instance the less common word appears just once. Or 906 if it appears twice and so on.

Comment: @nicola I want to know, in the randomized data set, the saturation. In other words I want to know at which point no new words are added. To take the current example, there are 907 data points represented by 103 individual words, which have very different frequency. I would then want to know the cut-off point for the inclusion of new words, e.g. at 300, 500 or 700. Does that make sense?

Comment: Suppose that your least frequent word happens twice. If you draw randomly the words from your dataset, you may be unlucky and never draw this uncommon word until it is the only left in the pack, i.e. after you have already drawn all the words except the last two. So there isn't a cut-off point, not as you seem to think. You may ask: how may words do I have to draw to be 95% sure to get all the words? But if you want to be sure, you need to draw all the words less the number of times of the least frequent plus one.

Comment: @nicola Ok, I think I understand your point. So how would I go about answering "how many words do I have to draw to be 95% sure to get all the words?

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow. Try CrossValidated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/